# MatchIt warning: order of the match is not guaranteed?

Tags: r

When I run this example from the `MatchIt` package I get the following warning:

```
library(MatchIt)
data(lalonde, package = 'MatchIt')
m.out <- matchit(treat ~ re74 + re75 + age + educ, data = lalonde, method = "optimal", distance = "logit", ratio = 2)
Warning message:
  In fullmatch(d, min.controls = ratio, max.controls = ratio, omit.fraction = (n0 -  :
                                                                                 Without 'data' argument the order of the match is not guaranteed
                                                                               to be the same as your original data.
```

I took the example from page 7 of their [paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v42/i08/paper)

Why do I get this warning?

Comment: I just installed MatchIt. Running the same example, I dont get an error. Are you running an old version of R?

Comment: I tried R 3.2.0 on linux and R 3.2.1 on windows.

Comment: same thing with  3.2.2 on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know why you get the warning but I do not know of a work around. You get the error because using `method="optimal"` requires the library `optmatch`. `matchit` is calling `optmatch::fullmatch` without setting the `data` argument. It is unlikely that there is something wrong with the output of `matchit`; it is just warning you that order of the match is not guaranteed.

Comment: is this a bug in `matchit `?

Comment: not 100% sure...might be worth an email to the Maintainer of the package

Comment: *Note:* I've submitted a [ticket on GitHub](https://github.com/kosukeimai/MatchIt/issues/18)